# How to create a VIEW that unions date partitioned tables dynamically based on a sliding date window

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table with millions of records that I would like to partition on date for maintenance convenience, so table_2011_01_01, table_2011_01_02.

For calculations I would like to have a view that unions those tables dynamically based on a sliding date window. For example a view that unions the tables of the last three days. In the mysql VIEW documentation I couldn't find an easy way to make the underlying select dynamically UNION tables for the last 3 days.

What's a good way to do that in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you partition a table, there's no need to address the separate partitions expicitly.
MySQL will do that for you.

So you don't need a `union` and you don't need to specify tables, you can just write a select that accesses a single table, if multiple partitions are needed, MySQL will union them automatically.

**Links:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html
Be sure to read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html

Comment: I don't want to use the PARTITION feature of mysql as the partitioning is fixed, more the partition concept regarding tables.

Comment: @Ward, reimplementing MySQL's partitioning feature is a bad idea, it will be slow, error prone and difficult to maintain. I strongly recommend using MySQL's build in partitioning support.